# Android streaming audio/video can't stream a rtsp file?

Tags: android, video, streaming, rtsp

I want to stream a media file on web, and android developer website has said that `MediaPlayer.setDataSource()` can set the data source (file-path or http/rtsp URL) to use.
But I got an error in both G1 device and emulator when streaming a rtsp url file: Command `PLAYER_PREPARE` completed with an error or info PVMFailure  error`(1, -1)`.

Does anyone know what is this error, or anyone knows where can I get the error description `(1, -1)` means?

P.S. the code can work successfully when playing a audio/video file or streaming a http protocal sudio/video file, but can't stream rtsp protocal file. Is android not supported rtsp streaming?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the emulator supports video at all, or didn't last time I checked (SDK 1.0 and 1.1) which failed with the exact same error. I'm not sure about 1.5 but from your report it sounds like it still doesn't.

Of course, I could be wrong, but when making beebPlayer, I found it was just easier to deploy straight to the device!

Answer (score 1):

```
Is android not supported rtsp streaming?
```

No, Android supports RTSP streaming. I have setup [`Darwin Streaming Server`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_Streaming_Server) (the open sourced RTP/RTSP streaming server), and successfully played a video (on my ADP2 phone with donut image) using RTSP Url. Url which I used is of the form:

```
rtsp://server_ip:554/file_name
```

There have been already provided some sample files while server set up which you can try to play. If you want to play your file, then you have to hint them first.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same problem. In one of the blog they say that it supports RTSP stream which satisfies the set of rules. I don't know which RTSP url supports all those rules. 
So what I have done is I have written my own RTSP client to get the streams and I have passed it to Player.

Answer (score 0):

Today I got some new information, it seems that android OPENCore has some bugs in streaming, and newer version 2.04 has fixed these problems, but I can't find what version now my code is. someone said ChangeLog has version information (/external/opencore/ChangeLog) , but I can't find where this ChangeLog file is. Does anyone know where this file is and how could I update OPENCore version? Thanks

Comment: allen, could you please share more information about the bug? thanks